# How to unstake system token?

Tags: staking

I'm trying EOSIO boot-up sequence using EOSIO wiki page.

I succeeded setting contracts, creating accounts and producers, and producing blocks from some other nodeoses.

But I can't find any method that Unstaking SYS from accounts...

Is there any actions or methods to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the documentation for undelegating bandwidth. I'd assume the command would look like below:

```
cleos system undelegatebw FROM RECEIVER unstake_net_quantity unstake_cpu_quantity
```

**system undelegatebw**
Undelegate bandwidth

**Positional Arguments**

```
from TEXT - The account undelegating bandwidth
receiver TEXT - The account to undelegate bandwidth from
unstake_net_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to undelegate for network bandwidth
unstake_cpu_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to undelegate for CPU bandwidth
```

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-undelegatebw

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, after 3 days, which method or command can I use?

Comment: I updated my post with the cleos command.  That is what you would do in cleos to begin the 3 day process.  After you can transfer the token.  You should be able to piece together what is needed by trying that in the command line and putting -h after to help with the optional positionals.  There are also a host of options offered after the pos args.

Comment: So, after 3 days (after command "cleos undelegatebw"), 
For tranferring funds, Should I use a command like "cleos push action eosio refund '{"owner":"accountname"}' -p accountname ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you could transfer funds with:

./cleos transfer useraaaaaaaa useraaaaaaac "1.0000 SYS"

Positional Parameters
sender TEXT - The account sending tokens
recipient TEXT - The account receiving tokens
amount UINT - The amount of tokens to send
symbol TEXT - The memo for the transfer
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-transfer